# Call Main.js globally after JQuery script - YII2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, bundle

In a view I called:

```
<?php 
$this->registerJsFile(
    '@web/../dist/js/main.js',
    ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]
);
?>
```

To load my `main.js` script immediately after the JQuery one, and it works.

Now my aim is to load `main.js` after JQuery in each view of my program.
I'm using `yii2 advanced template`, so in both backend and frontend AppAsset I'm trying to recreate globally what I've obtained in a single view, I modified the `$depends` array but without any success.

Comment: What do you mean by "right track"? Is there anything not working so far?

Comment: As now the things are working, but I don't know if the $depends array is the right configuration to modify and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try use POS_END

```
$this->registerJsFile(
    '@web/../dist/js/main.js',
    ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END]]
);
```

But  if you need  a general solution  .. then you could try using a proper layout where you load/register the asset or the jsFile you need  and  then you could use this layer in the controller or in the controller action you need

or you could create a proper asset and register this asset in your
 layout

Comment: I modified the question, maybe now is more clear on what I'm trying to achieve.